# Picking data from database that appeard just once in a month

Tags: mysql, join

I have a table and in that bank transactions are recorded. I want to pull out the users who made transaction just once in a month. That means their transaction count == 1 for that month.

I am recording card_number, timestamp  etc..

Comment: Try offering up your database layout, and the code you've tried so far

Comment: give us a table definition to work with...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM transactions
GROUP BY card_number, month
HAVING COUNT(card_number) = 1
```

Comment: I don't think his requirements say it has to be for a particular month only.  I interpreted it as display all transactions where only the count of equals 1 per month so I stand by my answer.

Comment: @Wes: I don't know, maybe you're right. Question is not "so clear" about this :)

Comment: @marco Indeed point being he needs to use a group by and having count() to solve his real problem so we got that part covered

Comment: @Wes yes, I think you're right. +1 for you and I deleted my post Good job :)

Comment: @Wes: perhpas you'd better to use MONTH(your-date) instead of month, because I think in db he stores a date

Comment: @marco You might be right but I've put enough mindshare into this vague question :)

Answer (score 0):

**Check This**

```
select     Card_Number,
           DATEPART(m, [TimeStamp] )MonthNo,
           COUNT(1) TxnCount
from       Transactions
group by   Card_Number,
           DATEPART(m, [TimeStamp] )
having     COUNT(1)=1
```

I am assuming that your table structure is somthing like below.

```
Card_Number int, 
TimeStamp  datetime
```

Comment: also no need to have `count(`) txncount` in the select.  Instead just say `'1' TxnCount` because the count is always the same so why use a function to produce the result?

Comment: @Wes: I edited his code, but I think someone discared my edits. If so -1